Detecting when HKWorkoutSession is being forcibly closed/ended in background
I noticied that my workout session is sometimes being killed by apple when the app is in the background and it seems that the func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date) {} is only being called when the app comes back into the foreground.
I wonder if there is a way for us to get notified when the workout is about to die or has already been killed.
Thanks

Workouts are one of the few approved background modes. There is likely something else happening.

This indicates your app has been killed. As you note, you'll get the notification when the app is relaunched. There is no way, by design, to be notified when an app is being killed. This can happen for a variety of reasons, including the battery running out or the device crashing. There is no way in the general case for this to work. Apple also does not try to make it work in cases where it could. Your app must handle that situation.
